# using pickle in python

Tags: python, pickle

I'm working with pickle in python I use this code:

```
fe = input("Enter the file you want: ")
f = calculate_hash(fe)

handle = open('filename.pickle', 'rb') 
b = pickle.load(handle)
strings = re.findall(f, handle.read())

if strings:
    print "yes"     # here I want to change/edit the "Last time scanned"
else:
    print "no"      
    v = {f:{"file name":fe,"Last time scanned":time.strftime("%c")}}
    print v
    with open('filename.pickle', 'ab') as handle:
        pickle.dump(v, handle)
```

I need help in the part "print "yes"" that I want to modify just the "Last time scanned". as (v) already exist but i want just to change the time. how could I do that

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're running? Is your pickle file called `filename.pickle`? Why is that hardcoded in your code?

Comment: yes it is handle = open('filename.pickle', 'ab')

Comment: So what is the point of asking the user for a file, then (since you never look at that file)?

Comment: I want to change just the time in the dictionary v = {f:{"file name":fe,"Last time scanned":time.strftime("%c")}}

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is update "Last time scanned", you should be able to do it like this:

```
fe = input("Enter the file you want: ")
f = calculate_hash(fe)

handle = open('filename.pickle', 'rb') 
b = pickle.load(handle)
strings = re.findall(f, handle.read())

if strings:
    print "yes"     # here I want to change/edit the "Last time scanned"
    v[fe]["Last time scanned"] = time.strftime("%c")
else:
    print "no"      
    v = {f:{"file name":fe,"Last time scanned":time.strftime("%c")}}
    print v
    with open('filename.pickle', 'ab') as handle:
        pickle.dump(v, handle)
```

However, this is bad design, as `"Last time scanned"` is a string, making it very difficult to refactor (what happens if you want to change it to "last scanned", for instance). You might therefore be better off with an instance of a custom class object.

Comment: I'm sorry but does the file "filename.pickle" updated ?? if not please how could be updated ??

Comment: handle is never closed before you open it again, might be nicer using seek or using with to open both times.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It's very unclear what OP is trying to do. I suspect that everything after `f = ...` is in a while loop or similar. If not, the question doesn't really make sense

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yes but the update you made on the v not on the file itself

Comment: @user3832061: I have a feeling that you need to update your question to be much more detailed than it currently is

Comment: Seems the question is not about pickle at all - but how to access items in dictionaries.